# How to run and kill processes in Fedora from a Java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, process, fedora, kill

I'm working in Fedora. I want to create a GUI in Java with two buttons: START and STOP. I have two processes: p1 and p2. When I click on START, p1 should run in the background and p2 should run in the foreground. (In the terminal, we do this by giving `./p1` and `./p2`.) When I click on STOP, both the processes should be killed. (The terminal equivalent is: CTRL+C and kill -9 pid).

Can anyone suggest the way to do this?

Comment: What part of the Java standard ProcessBuilder and Process classes don't work for you?

Comment: i havent tried this before , can you kindly elaborate..

Comment: How about checking javadoc for `ProcessBuilder` and reading a couple of lines how to use it? Do we need to paste all internet here on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, in java you can use the Process and ProcessBuilder API's to start other processes.

The following links point to relevant API documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

According to the API docs, you can start processes, pass command line arguments and environment variables to them, access their input and output streams and kill them.

There are also several related questions here on Stack Overflow that may be able to help e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java).