# Java: How to open a program using the command line and interact

Tags: java, runtime, cmd, inputstream, outputstream

I searched a lot the last hours to open program.exe and interact with it like cmd. The solutions I found did not work or just worked for opening cmd and running commands like 'dir'.

I want to open a program (lets say program.exe), entering a command, parsing the output and then entering the next command. The window of the command line does not have to be open/visible but I need to get the output and enter further commands. How can I do this with Java?

Comment: Is the [Java Tutorial on Command Line Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java) thread will give you some direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you may be referring to opening another process and running a command-line program from it and passing arguments to this secondary process.

If so, what you are looking for is the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

You can create a [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) and obtain an input stream to read from it, or an output stream to write back at it.

You might want to check the following examples:

- [Executing a command](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html)
- [Redirecting the output of a command](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ReadFromCommand.html).
- [Sending input to a command](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/WriteToCommand.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Runtime. It is an object every application has and is there to interact with the environment.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

You can start a program with "exec" which will return an Process instance. You can access the output stream by calling "process.getOutputStream();"