# How to schedule shell script from java program

Tags: java, linux, scheduling

I have a constraint on the server, hence Cron/Autosys is not available for scheduling shell scripts. Is there a way we can schedule a shell script from a java program ? Is quartz scheduler useful ?
Can some one provide me a sample code for the same.

Answer (score 3):

The below tutorial help you to schedule shell script.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-run-a-task-periodically-in-java/

By using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh shellscript.sh");
```

You can run shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ProcessBuilder class for executing any process externally from java including batch files. Here [Executing another application from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java) there is an example.

Instead of timer class, creating a thread checking time with small intervals might solve the time dependency.

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    void run () {    
        while(true) {     
            if(myTime != currentTime) {
                // check for the time until your time has come
                // if not, sleep and continue
                sleep(1000);
                continue;
            }

            // Do your job and exit when necessary 
        }
    }
}
```

you can execute the class with thread.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of use to you : http://algorithmicallyrandom.blogspot.in/2009/11/tips-and-tricks-scheduling-jobs-without.html

You can use the [`at`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/at1.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timer:

```
int loopTime = 1000*60*60*12;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask()
{
        public void run()
        {
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your java command: java -classpath...");
    }
},0, loopTime);   //0 is for delay time in ms, loopTime is also in ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation) to schedule your task from Java. Your [Job](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Job.html) implementation would then invoke [Runtime.exec(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) to launch the shell task, and possibly some [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) methods to interact with the task. Some tips:

- As you are going to launch a shell script, rather than directly invoking your shell script with `Runtime.exec(...)` you should invoke your *shell executable*  and pass your shell script as parameter. That is, instead of exec'ing `/path/to/your/shell/script.sh`, you should exec `sh /path/to/your/shell/script.sh`.
- Quartz scheduler supports cron expressions, see [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/triggers/CronTriggerImpl.html) and [tutorial on supported cron expressions](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) in Quartz.
- Obviously, Quartz scheduler jobs will only run as long as you have a JVM running with the Quartz Scheduler service up. Usually you need to take this into account when implementing your jobs.
- Also, if you do not implement some sort of job persistence, such as [JobStoreCMT](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/JobStoreCMT.html), you might skip job executions, and dynamically scheduled job executions will not survive a restart.