# Need to gather console application output and store it

Tags: java

Lets say, that i have launched simple Java application, that outputs some strings to standart console using following command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Path:/to/app.exe");
```

What i need is to gather all data, that launched app throws to the console. Is it possible? Thanks.

Paul.

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and get its `IutputStream`. Here is simple example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] processArgs = new String[]{"ping","google.com"};
    Process process = new ProcessBuilder(processArgs).start();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            //I'am using Win7 with PL encoding in console -> "CP852"
            process.getInputStream(), "CP852"));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

    in.close();
    System.out.println("process ended");
}
```