# Is it possible for a JVM to run more than one program at the same time?

Tags: java, jvm

Is it possible for a JVM to run more than one program at the same time? If so, how? If not, why?

To run a program, we simply do

```
java ProgramName
```

But can we use the same JVM instance to run another program?

Comment: What about a multi-threaded program?

Comment: You've got a point there Fouad, but it is essentially the same "program".

Comment: Threads share resources. So, if you have a static variable, you can access it from any thread. Otherwise, why do you need 2 programs to be run in the same JVM?

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires the same instance but a different program, as opposed to just running `java Program2`?

Comment: This is just a question to satisfy my curiosity. :)

Comment: Not typically. You can however, there are a few vendor-specific multi process JVMs that support running multiple processes within a single JVM. A good O'Reilly article is available here: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/09/25/optimization.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer depends on your definition of "program." The Java programs that have a `main` method and that you start with `java NameOfClass` typically cannot be run in the same JVM because there's no builtin separation of resources or namespaces. For example, what if the two programs use conflicting versions of the same library?

We also have applications that are designed to share a JVM, such as enterprise applications. These are programs that are designed to run in the context of an "application server", which is basically a program for running other programs. An application server keeps the applications resources separate using classloaders and security managers. For example, two applications may use conflicting versions of a library or conflicting class names and still share a JVM thanks to being loaded through different classloaders.

Comment: To my understanding OSGi solves the separation of jars in different classloaders.

Comment: I wouldn't close out simply to implement a `.jar`, whose `static main()` simply loads multiple jars and calls their `static main()` on different threads. Yes, it would be problematic on namespace/resource collisions, but mainly it would work.

Answer (score 4):

Not directly. However, since the JVM does support threading, you can paste both programs together by creating a wrapper that starts each one up in a different thread (assuming they're compatible and don't do stuff like define different classes with the same name).

If you don't want the programs to be able to interfere with each other at all or share any state, what's the point of even running them in the same process? If all you want to do is conserve memory by only loading the standard library once, you can set up `SecurityManagers` and `ClassLoaders` to isolate the two programs. However, this necessarily prevents them from doing crazy stuff with reflection.

Answer (score 3):

If you are executing JAVA command from command prompt, it will always run on separate JVM instance.You can use separate threads for the programs if you want to use the same JVM. But with JAVA command it will be two separate processes, hence separate JVM.

Answer (score 2):

IBM is developing a "multi-tenant" JVM http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-multitenant-java/ which would make it possible/easier to run multiple Java programs inside the same virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

One one hand, you cannot. JVM runs only one program. On other hand, the starting program can simply run another programs, sequentially or in parallel. Sequential way is especially simple:

```
ClassName1.main(new String[]{arg1, arg2});
ClassName2.main(new String[]{arg1, arg2, arg3});
```

Answer (score 0):

To run `java` command you need to use

```
java [ options ] class [ argument ... ]
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ argument ... ]
```

Also from [`java` - the Java application launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) we can read that

> The **java** tool launches a Java application. It does this by starting a Java runtime environment, loading a **specified** class, and invoking that class's **main** method.

So `java` creates process for JVM which will load **one** class and invoke its **main** method.

I don't see any options to add other classes with for executing its main methods via `java` command. If you want you can start new thread/[process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778022/1393766) inside your program, but it wont change the fact that JVM will run only one **main** method at start.