# Opening and closing application from Java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I'm trying to use `ProcessBuilder` to start application in ***cmd.exe***, wait for it to finish and then close it. So far I tried:

```
String[] cmdline=new Stirng{}("cmd.exe","/C","start",application_and_parameters);
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdline);
Process p = processBuilder.start();
//get error and input streams
int exitVal = p.waitFor();
```

It opens window as expected, but doesn't close. I tried:

```
p.destroy()
```

and to send exit command:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
writer.write("exit");
writer.flush();
```

but without success, cmd stays. Could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java

Answer (score 0):

Remove start , It will execute your process directly without opening command prompt so you will not need to close it manually.Below is you code snippet  as an example

```
String[] cmdline=new String[]{"cmd.exe","/C","notepad.exe"};
                ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdline);
                Process p = processBuilder.start();
                //get error and input streams
                int exitVal = p.waitFor();
                System.out.println(exitVal);
```