# Run a C program when called by a Java program

Tags: java, c

I can't seem to find any relevant information on this.

As an example, lets assume I have two integers on a Java application, I wish to send it to a C program using sockets. The C program then adds them together and returns the result back to the java program that displays it. I don't want the user having to start a C program themselves, it should be done via Java

I done some research and know using native commands wouldn't be appropriate as I need the C program to return some information.

How would I go across starting a C program through java?

Comment: Sounds like `native` methods here.

Comment: you could try a ProcessBuilder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java