# how to pass parameter to shell script to use as part of variable filename

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am trying to programmatically call from my java program a shell script that in turn executes a command depending of the parameter sent.

the command to be executed inside the connectvpn.sh shell script is:

```
echo myrootpassword | sudo -S /usr/local/Cellar/openvpn/2.3.8/sbin/openvpn --config /usr/local/etc/openvpn/1.opvn
```

or

```
echo myrootpassword | sudo -S /usr/local/Cellar/openvpn/2.3.8/sbin/openvpn --config /usr/local/etc/openvpn/2.opvn
```

and so on from a long list, where the filename number I want to be variable depending on the value of the parameter received

So I want my java program to be able to use always the same shell script but use different .ovpn file depending on the parameter sent.

I believe that on my java program I have to call it something like this:

```
server_number = 1;    

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./connectvpn.sh", server_number);
Process proc = pb.start();
```

What would go in the shell script so that the filename called is variable and for the example shown it uses 1 but other times it uses whatever number is sent as parameter?

Thank you very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java

Comment: ok, thanks, but that does not answer my question about the parameter

Comment: You can pass parameters in array list. List<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
args.add ("script.bat"); // command name
args.add ("-option"); // optional args added as separate list items
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (args);.

Comment: If I got it correct - you are trying to pass a variable parameters to your Java program? You can do that by calling the "main" class of your Java program with the appropriate parameters. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell script, use `$1` to denote the first parameter passed to it.

Fix your java as below,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./connectvpn.sh", String.valueOf(server_number));
```

Comment: thanks, so inside the shell script I would have: echo myrootpassword | sudo -S /usr/local/Cellar/openvpn/2.3.8/sbin/openvpn --config /usr/local/etc/openvpn/$1.opvn ?

Comment: yes. Try it out and see.

Comment: My java program is giving me this error that I must solve first so if you know what's the problem please tell me: "The error message was: class bsh.EvalError (line 18): new ProcessBuilder ( "./connectvpn.sh" , server_number ) --Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``//import java.io.IOException; //import java.util.*; import java.lang.ProcessBuil . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Constructor error: Can't find constructor: java.lang.ProcessBuilder( java.lang.String, int ) in class: java.lang.ProcessBuilder". First time I use ProcessBuilder so might have forgotten to include something

Comment: As the error says, the constructor cannot be found. You are calling `ProcessBuilder(String, int)`. The acceptable constructors are `ProcessBuilder(List<String>)` or `ProcessBuilder(String...)`.  
Check my edited answer above.