# Creating a I/O stream in java to collect data from Linux/Solaris environment

Tags: java

On linux/solaris machine i am executing one command through Java , now I want to collect the output of this command in a Java stream.Any suggestion how to do that.?

Comment: what's the command?

Comment: check out the Process Builder API. you can get the outputstream of that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java

Comment: @nlloyd - the command i am using is 'sar -A 1'