# how to make and run executable files with java?

Tags: java, maven, cross-platform

I want that my java program be able to create a file with commands to run,
After the program done to create the file I want that the program execute the file.The commands will be maven commands like this - `mvn deploy:deploy-file`.
Maven is in my path in all the servers so i can run the command from the terminal.

I need that the code will work on Linux and Windows. Any ideas of libraries that can help me implement this?

My main issue is what extension I need to give the file so I can execute it from java in Windows and Linux environments

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. If you want to invoke Maven commands, look into [Maven Invoker](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-invoker/).

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java

Comment: @Tunaki this answer saved me a lot of time. Thanks!!