# Sends a text message to a specific number phone

Tags: android, telegram

I got `App api_id`, `App api_hash` and `Production configuration` from `telegram.org`, I need to use from this method `messages.sendMessage` for    Sends a text message to a specific number phone's telegram(for example: +1888888). How can I use from this method. Is there any a simple sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you using a top-layer library over MTProto to make things easier. For example you can use [Telethon](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You should use [SendMessageRequest](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/messages/send_message.html) in order to send message. After [creating a client](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/basic/creating-a-client.html) you can call it like this (in newest version of Telethon the phone number is resolved automatically):

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendMessageRequest
client(SendMessageRequest('phone_number', 'hello'))
```

If you're using TDLib, you may use this function (taken from [here](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/java/org/drinkless/tdlib/example/Example.java)) or a similar one:

```
private static void sendMessage(long chatId, String message) {
    // initialize reply markup just for testing
    TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton[] row = {new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton("https://telegram.org?1", new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButtonTypeUrl()), new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton("https://telegram.org?2", new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButtonTypeUrl()), new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton("https://telegram.org?3", new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButtonTypeUrl())};
    TdApi.ReplyMarkup replyMarkup = new TdApi.ReplyMarkupInlineKeyboard(new TdApi.InlineKeyboardButton[][]{row, row, row});

    TdApi.InputMessageContent content = new TdApi.InputMessageText(new TdApi.FormattedText(message, null), false, true);
    client.send(new TdApi.SendMessage(chatId, 0, false, false, replyMarkup, content), defaultHandler);
}
```

Don't forget that, you need to add each phone number to user's Telegram contacts first to get the `chatId`. It can be achieved by passing an array of phone numbers to this function:

```
---functions---
contacts.importContacts#2c800be5 contacts:Vector<InputContact> = contacts.ImportedContacts
```

Comment: My code is java,can i use from telethon in my project?

Comment: Directly, no. However you can use `ProcessBuilder` to run your python script. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468987/executing-another-application-from-java

Comment: I accept your answer but if you have a link simple sample for use telethon in java androi get me.plaese.thanks a lot

Comment: if you want to use it in android, you'd better look at the official TDLib here: https://github.com/tdlib/td

Comment: Also look at Java examples of TDLib: https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/java

Comment: I just need to send message from my app to telegram contact list phone with this library.Thank's a lot

Comment: I can't use from TDLib.Get me this error: By not providing "FindTd.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked
  CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Td", but CMake did
  not find one.

Comment: And I can't install C++14 compatible compiler.